# How to read QR Code scanner data from a non-android scanner in Java

Tags: java, qr-code

In my project, I created QRCode Image that stored encrypted user information.
now, I have to learn how to take encrypted user information data, that is sent by a scanner(not android phone), in my java web application(using jsp and servlet).
I search a lot, related this particle, but I get only some particle, that show how to use with android phone.
So, Can you give me a link or some e-books to learn how to take and insert the data into web page's text boxes using a qr code scanner.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you having a problem getting data from a scanner (if so, what scanner type e.g. is it emulating a serial port) or do you have the data and need to decrypt it?

Comment: I am just only having a problem I don't know how to getting data from a scanner, because I have never deal with a scanner before and I want to learn the java code about it. I don't know what scanner type because our company is just order a scanner now. So, I will first to learn about this until the scanner get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, most scanners work like a keyboard, so reading from standard input will give you the string of bytes that was just read. How you interpret them depends on the data format in your scanner. This is usually good, but won't work if you have more than one scanner, or if someone is going to be using the keyboard at the same time.

The alternative is a scanner that can be set up to emulate an RS-232 serial port. In that case, you can use a library such as [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/) that lets you open a stream to a serial port and read the data coming in.

The mode the scanner is in is often programmable using a barcode that comes in the manual. Upon scanning it, the scanner changes mode.

Comment: Thank for ur answer. Let me check..

Comment: To answer me back, firstly thanks to you. So, can you give me some sample coding just only how to capture the data in java method, when the scanner scanned the qrcode image.

Comment: Part of the point is it doesn't matter if it's a barcode scanner, an RFID reader or any other RS-232 device. They will all provide an `InputStream` you can read. Here are some [examples for RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Examples)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this answer is really support me a lot.

Comment: No problem, and good luck with it! Last note: if you do RS232 emulations (COM port mode or whatever they call it) you can figure out which one is the data from *your* scanner. If it works as a keyboard, you'll have a hard time telling user keystrokes from reader input, so try to set it up as COM if at all possible